# Counting words from tokenized url

Tags: python, count, tokenize, words

Very new to Python and was hoping you guys could give me some help.

I have a book about The Great War, and want to count the times a country appears in the book. So far i have this:

```
>>> from __future__ import division 
>>> import nltk, re, pprint
>>> from urllib import urlopen
>>> url = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/29270/29270.txt"
>>> raw = urlopen(url).read() 
>>> type(raw)
<type 'str'>
>>> len(raw)
1067008
>>> raw[:75]
'The Project Gutenberg EBook of The Story of the Great War, Volume II (of\r\nV'
>>>
```

Tokenization.
Break up the string into words and punctuation.

```
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
>>> type(tokens)
<type 'list'>
>>> len(tokens)
189743
>>> tokens[:10] //vind de eerste 10 tokens
['The', 'Project', 'Gutenberg', 'EBook', 'of', 'The', 'Story', 'of', 'the', 'Great']
>>>
```

Correcting Beginning and Ending of book

```
    >>> raw.find("PART I")
    >>> 2629
    >>> raw.rfind("End of the Project Gutenberg")
    >>> 1047663
    >>> raw = raw[2629:1047663]
    >>> raw.find("PART I")
    >>> 0
```

I unfortunately have no idea how to implement the book into the wordcount. My ideal outcome would be something like this:

```
Germany 2000
United Kingdom 1500
USA 1000
Holland 50
Belgium 150
```

etc.

Please help!

Comment: Thank you very much. Another question. Holland has been counted 10 times. Is it also possible to show the lines in which the word Holland is said? So the output will be 10 lines where Holland appears

Answer (score 1):

Python has a builtin method to count a substring in a string.

```
from urllib import urlopen

url = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/29270/29270.txt"
raw = urlopen(url).read()
raw = raw[raw.find("PART I"):raw.rfind("End of the Project Gutenberg")]

countries = ['Germany', 'United Kingdom', 'USA', 'Holland', 'Belgium']
for c in countries:
    print c, raw.count(c)
```

produces

```
Germany 117
United Kingdom 0
USA 0
Holland 10
Belgium 63
```

edit: eumiro is right, this doesn't work if you want to count the exact word. Use this if you want to search for the exact word:

```
import re
from urllib import urlopen

url = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/29270/29270.txt"
raw = urlopen(url).read()
raw = raw[raw.find("PART I"):raw.rfind("End of the Project Gutenberg")]

for key, value in {c:len(re.findall(c + '[^A-Za-z]', raw)) for c in countries}.items():
    print key, value
```

edit: if you want the linenumbers:

```
from urllib import urlopen
import re
from collections import defaultdict

url = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/29270/29270.txt"
raw = urlopen(url).readlines()

count = defaultdict(list)
countries = ['Germany', 'United Kingdom', 'USA', 'Holland', 'Belgium']
for c in countries:
    for nr, line in enumerate(raw):
        if re.search(c + r'[^A-Za-z]', line):
            count[c].append(nr + 1) #nr + 1 so the first line is 1 instead of 0
    print c, len(count[c]), 'lines:', count[c]
```

Comment: `USA` could be a part of a longer abbreviation and counted with `.count` (although it is not the case in this text).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Another question. Holland has been counted 10 times. Is it also possible to show the lines in which the word Holland is said? So the output will be 10 lines where Holland appears

Comment: Question nr. 2: What if i for example the words German, Germany, Germans. Can I combine these and how?

Comment: By the way, it seems that my answer answers your question, so please accept it.

Comment: Nr. 2 is too simplified. In general you use a so called stemming algorithm for such a task. For example there is the [PyStemmer library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyStemmer).

Comment: I think a stemming algorithm is overkill in this situation. Also, my suggestion for nr. 2 was just a quick thought, which is also why I didn't include it in the real answer. While stemming is indeed useful when searching for variants of a word, the question clearly states that he is new to python, and I think a regex is a lot easier.